# Computr Sci Ranking. Which Group Is Most Selective?

Tags: sorting, computer-science, ranking

There are four groups ( sort of like jobs or colleges ): A, B, C, and D. In the project, there will be many more, but for now let's assume four. People can apply to any number those groups, and the groups can reject or admit them. Person 1 got in to A, B, C, D. Person 2 got into A, B, C, but not D. Person 3 got into A, B, but not C, D. Person 4 got into A, but not B, C, D, E. Obviously, A is least selective, followed by B, C, and lastly D. How does a computer figure this out when there are any number of groups, and any number of people who applied to any number of groups? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: by counting the rate of acceptance?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I considered your exact comment, but then decided to be a bit nicer!

Comment: I'm confused. People don't have to apply to all groups, so counting won't work, correct? I mean, the acceptance is relative.

Answer (score 0):

I would use (by analogy with colleges) acceptance rate as the criterion to sort on.

```
                    number of people accepted by group X
acceptance rate = -----------------------------------------
                    number of people applying to group X
```

I'm not really sure what else you could use.  A group can only consider the people who applied to it.

Comment: possibly, but if I had wanted to do that, I would not have posted the question on the internet. People don't have to apply to all groups, as I said, so that method would not work properly.

Comment: apology, it would not work the way intended. acceptance is relative. what if 40 ppl apply to the least selective group and get rejected bcuz theyre just that bad? i need a method where acceptance is relative.

Comment: How do you know any group is the least selective before anyone's applied?  How do we know the people are "that bad"? Where is that information coming from?

As you've formulated the problem, all we we know is which people apply to which groups and which groups accept which people.  We have no *a priori* knowledge of the abilities of the people and the selectivity of the groups.  Acceptance rate is pretty much all you have to work with.

Comment: thats not true. those who apply to two groups and get into one but not the other show that the one they got into is less selective. if that person had gotten into both, we cud just ignore it becuz no new info is given. thank u for trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution to this problem may be hard to get, since you can easily get cycles (i.e., no transitivity):

```
A accepts x and rejects y;
B accepts y and rejects z;
C accepts z and rejects x.
```

And institutions may not be strictly comparable (i.e., no symmetry):

```
A accepts x and rejects y;
B accepts y and rejects x.
```

One method you might try to employ is a network-based model. Let institutions be nodes. Add a directed arc with weight `w` from node A to node B where `w` is the number of applicants who were both accepted at institution B and rejected at institution A. Intuitively, the weight of arcs pointing at less selective schools will be larger. So the problem basically boils down to finding steady-state flows in and out of the nodes... Institutions outside of a component are incomparable.

Sorry for not going into greater detail on this, but I hope the idea is clear.